# Customize @PropertyResource handling behavior for java annotation based configuration

Tags: spring, annotations

I wish to customize the handling of the property source, while using java annotation based intializing a spring web application.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("ldap.properties")
@Repository
public class LdapDao {
...
    @Autowired
    public void setEnv(Environment env) throws NamingException {
    this.url = env.getProperty("url").trim();
    this.user = env.getProperty("user").trim();
    this.password = env.getProperty("password).trim();

    this.initializeLdapContext();
    }
...
}
```

In this case, spring will look for the property source on classpath. If the property source is declared as:

```
@PropertySource("file:/${conf.dir}/ldap.properties")
```

ldap.properties is searched under the directory specified by the system property "conf.dir".

I need the behavior where the property resource is first searched under the directory specified by the system property "conf.dir". If it is not found there, its location defaults to classpath.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
@PropertySource({"ldap.properties", "file:/${conf.dir}/ldap.properties"})
```

and you will get last one, just add in yours propConfig code

```
PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propConfig = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
//.....
propConfig.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
propConfig.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(false);
propConfig.setLocalOverride(true);
//....
```